# How do I append a text changing the number format?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, append, number-formatting

I'm getting number from a HTML, some of them are %, 4 digits and 7 digits (37.89%, 3.464, 2,193.813). I would like to save just the numbers, not the percentages, without the thousand separators (".").

```
        list_of_rows = []
        for row in table.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'quadrado'}):
            list_of_cells = []
            for cell in row.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'circulo'}):
                text = cell.text
                # print(text)
                for cell_index in row.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'triangulo'}):
                    text_index = cell_index.text
                    list_of_cells_index = [text, text_index] 
                    list_of_cells_index_clean = ','.join(list_of_cells_index) # remove brackets and ''
                    # print(list_of_cells_index_clean) 
                list_of_cells.append(list_of_cells_index_clean)
            list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

    outfile = open("./list.csv", "a") 
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

I would like to get:
`37.89%, 3464, 2193,813.`
How can I do it?

Comment: so for 37.89% the number should be just 37?

Comment: No, 37 needs to stay as it is. only numbers of thousands

Comment: So should  3.464 be  3 or  3464?

Comment: I would like to get:
`37.89%, 3464, 2193,813.`

Comment: So you want 2,193.813 to be 2193,813?

Comment: yes, and 3,464 -> 3464

Comment: Why 2193,813 and not 2,193,813 or 2193813?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your input parameters, but this works for the ones that you provided.

```
s = ('37.89%', '3.464', '2,193.813')

for item in s:
  remove_comma = item.replace(',', '')
  keep_percentage = re.findall(r'\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}%', remove_comma)
  if keep_percentage:
     keep_percentage = ''.join(keep_percentage)
     print (keep_percentage)
  else:
    if (len(remove_comma)) == 5:
        print (remove_comma.replace('.', ''))
    else:
        print (remove_comma.replace('.', ','))

**OUTPUTS**
37.89%
3464
2193,813
```